# How to get key object out of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, multidimensional-array

I have an array that consist of an object like this

```
 [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

each object contains this

```
label: (7) ["Billboard", "Lamppost", "LED Billboard", "Newspaper", "Influencer", "Radio", "Television"]
value: (7) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

what i really want to achieve is this

```
 const options = [
  { value: "0", label: "Billboard" },
  { value: "1", label: "Lamppost" },
  { value: "2", label: "Led billboard" },
  { value: "3", label: "Newspaper" },
  { value: "4", label: "Influencer" },
  { value: "5", label: "Radio" },
  { value: "6", label: "Television" },
 
];


[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]


0: {value: Array(7), label: Array(7)}
1: {value: Array(7), label: Array(7)}
2: {value: Array(7), label: Array(7)}
3: {value: Array(7), label: Array(7)}
4: {value: Array(7), label: Array(7)}
5: {value: Array(7), label: Array(7)}
6: {value: Array(7), label: Array(7)}
```

this is the data i have currently

Comment: From where "Chocolate", "Strawtberry"... come from in your output?

Comment: nope just populated the kind of data i want with that value

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, post the real object so we can understand

Comment: @TaiwoSulaimon Post exact input and output. Don't just populate with kind of data. And also mention your try

Comment: @MaheerAli populated it with right data

Comment: That's not helpful at all. We are talking about the `[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`, what are those `{…}`?

Comment: Please add the full array with the full code.

Comment: It would be great if you create codepen so we can run it and figure out the problem quickly.

Comment: use JSON.stringify(input,null, 2) to see proper response than paste it here, Don't copy-paste from the browser console without expanding object.

Comment: Are we looking for a loop, like `let result=[];for(let i=0;i<label.length;i++)result.push({value:value[i],label:label[i]});console.log(result);`? Or what?

Comment: 0:
label: (7) ["Billboard", "Lamppost", "LED Billboard", "Newspaper", "Influencer", "Radio", "Television"]
value: (7) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


this is what is in each object

Comment: Can you expand what value, the label contains in each object in that array? or is all objects is duplicated in the array?

Comment: So you want an array of arrays of objects, right? Like `[ [ { value: ..., label: ... }, { value: ..., label: ... }, ... ], [ { value: ..., label: ... }, { value: ..., label: ... }, ... ], ... ]`

Comment: no i want something like this

 const options = [
  { value: "0", label: "Billboard" },
  { value: "1", label: "Lamppost" },
  { value: "2", label: "Led billboard" },
  { value: "3", label: "Newspaper" },
  { value: "4", label: "Influencer" },
  { value: "5", label: "Radio" },
  { value: "6", label: "Television" },
 
];

Comment: how? The input array contains multiple objects, shouldn't all those result in an array of smaller objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumming you current array contains duplicates of the same data, this is how you turn that array into the one you want.

```js
const options = oldArray[0].value.map((value,index) => ({
   value,
   label: oldArray[0].label[index],
)});
```